# How to redirect all subdomains to domain/subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all subdomains to the main domain using .htaccess, but I want to keep the information about the subdomain and redirect that do domain.com/subdomain

so if for example:

subdomain.domain.com
*should be redirected to*
domain.com/subdomain

is there a way to achieve this using .htacces?
thank you very much.

Comment: Please do share your htaccess Rules file in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty straight forward:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as desired. That prevents annoying caching issues ...

You obviously need to rewriting module to be loaded and activated inside your http server. In general it makes sense to implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that (read: very cheap hosting provider), then you can use a distributed configuration file (often called ".htaccess"), but that comes with a number of disadvantages. For a start you need to take care that the interpretation of such files is enabled for your hosts (see the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation).